# [Java]How to set whats in ArrayList of objects to variables of different types?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an array list of objects that is filled with Strings, Doubles and Booleans.

```
     ArrayList<Object> nlist = new ArrayList<>();
     nlist.add(n.getUserName());//USerName is a string
     nlist.add(n.getWallet());// Wallet is a Double
     nlist.add(n.getAmountOfStorage());// Double
     nlist.add(n.isLoyal());// bool
     nlist.add(n.isPayAhead());// bool
     nlist.add(n.isRegular());//bool
```

This arraylist has been serialized to an .obj file. I want to read in the arraylist and set it to a list of variables. I tried something like this but no luck.

```
      try {
        ObjectInputStream filein = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(mainFile)));
        Object inObj = filein.readObject();
        if (inObj instanceof ArrayList) {
        int i = 0;
        ArrayList<Object> rlist = (ArrayList)inObj; //Arraylist of objects to set Variables to.
//tried this.
        n.setUserName(rlist.get(i));
        i++;
        n.setWallet(rlist.get(i));
        //continuing for a few more variables.
```

Whats the best way to get a list of objects set to variables of different types?

Comment: You don't. Lists are for variables of the same type. It looks like `n` already holds everything you need.

Comment: Why don't you just serialize the `n` object, whatever type that is?

Comment: You _maybe_ could but it will _always_ be a terrible idea.

Comment: I think instead of a `List<Object>`, you'd prefer a `Map<String, Object>` so you can assign names to values, and retrieve them accordingly (at least,  that would be viable outside of serialization). Since you're serializing, just set them inside the object itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ArrayList<Object> Array can hold basically any object, String, Integers, Longs, JButton, etc. etc. Now I'm not quite sure if this is what you're looking for but I'm going to give it a shot. If you want to know what object is contained within a specific ArrayList<Object> element then you can use a simple method as shown below:

```
public static String varType(final Object objectVar) {
    try {
      return objectVar.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { return null; }
}
```

How you might use this method:

```
JButton myButton = new JButton();
JTextField myTextField = new JTextField();
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();

ArrayList<Object> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add("My String");
a.add(23234);
a.add(376754356L);
a.add(345.74678D);
a.add(3.54f);
a.add(true);
a.add('A');
a.add(myButton);
a.add(myTextField);
a.add(myFrame);

for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Element at index " + i + " contains a " + 
                varType(a.get(i)) + " Object.");
}
```

Of course to place the elements of an Object ArrayList (which is Object by default) into their respective variables then you will need to need to cast them to it, for example:

```
JButton myButton = new JButton();
JTextField myTextField = new JTextField();
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();

ArrayList<Object> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add("My String");
a.add(23234);
a.add(376754356L);
a.add(345.74678D);
a.add(3.54f);
a.add(true);
a.add('A');
a.add(myButton);
a.add(myTextField);
a.add(myFrame);

//Ten elements within the Object ArrayList (0-9)
String myString = a.get(0).toString();
int myInt = (int) a.get(1);
long myLong = (long) a.get(2);
double myDouble = (double) a.get(3);
float myFloat = (float) a.get(4);
boolean myBoolean = (boolean) a.get(5);
char myChar = (char) a.get(6);
JButton myNewButton = (JButton) a.get(7);
JTextField myNewTextField = (JTextField) a.get(8);
JFrame myNewFrame = (JFrame) a.get(9);

System.out.println(varType(myString));
System.out.println(varType(myInt));
System.out.println(varType(myLong));
System.out.println(varType(myDouble));
System.out.println(varType(myFloat));
System.out.println(varType(myBoolean));
System.out.println(varType(myChar));
System.out.println(varType(myNewButton));
System.out.println(varType(myNewTextField));
System.out.println(varType(myNewFrame));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an ArrayList, you should create a class that holds all the variables you want as fields.

Then write that to the stream, instead.

Perhaps something like

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    String userName;
    Double wallet;
    Double amountOfStorage;
    boolean isLoyal;
    boolean isPayAhead;
    boolean isRegular;
}
```

When  you find yourself thinking about creating a container (List) with a variety of different types that are not related thru inheritance (other than Object) you are probably going down the wrong road.

Answer (score 0):

Never heard about POJO([Plain Old Java Object](https://www.quora.com/What-is-POJO-in-Java))?

you can use this Plain Old Java Object to store your different types of `Object` in one `Object` and then it will be the type of your `ArrayList`. It's like this:

```
public class NameOfObjectYouWant {
     String userName;
     Double wallet;
     Double amountOfStorage;
     Boolean isLoyal;
     Boolean isPayAhead;
     Boolean isRegular;

     // Getters and Setters Method....
}
```

You will set the values you want here in this kind of Object called `POJO`, and then add it on your `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<NameOfObjectYouWant> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
NameOfObjectYouWant n = new NameOfObjectYouWant();
n.setUserName("userName"); // Sample Inputs...
n.setWallet(232.42);
n.setAmountStorage(3000.00);
n.isLoyal(true);
n.isPayHead(true);
n.isRegular(true);
arrayList.add(n); // Add your n in your ArrayList..
```